# Submenu hiding behind content

Tags: html, css, asp.net, menu, navigation

Everything I've found says it is a z-index issue, but I've changed almost every element and nothing works.

Note that these are asp menus on a masterpage.  After setting the li items with a z-index of 9999 - I've attempted to put a div in the contentplaceholder and set it to z-index=1.  I've attempted setting the wrapping divs on pages to z-index=1.  None of it works.

http://sandbox.anacs.com/index.aspx  If you click on the 'Services' link, you'll see what I mean.

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or removed at a later stage (rendering your question useless). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ^ Sample HTML and CSS